# How to send push notification to 50 users

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, web-services

How to send Apple push notification to selected 50 users from database from .net webservice?

and also php web service? which would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# Library for sending APNS notifications: https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp

..and you'll definitely end up needing this article to set up your certificates http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate

Answer (score 1):

Sending to multiple users is the same as sending to one, really:

1. Device requests token from APNS
2. Device sends token to web service
3. Web service notices it wants to send a notification
4. Web service sends notification to APNS with user's token
5. Web service periodically listens for feedback to detect disabled devices etc

If you need to send 50 notifications, then at step 3 you'd work out all the tokens for users you want to send notification to, and you'd execute step 4 for each token.